# OnSelected doesn't run, instead OnCanceled runs

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to create a PopupMenuButton for my app. However, I ran into issues with selecting an option. The menu itself opens when clicked which is fine, the problem is that when I try to click on one of my options, my onSelected code doesn't run, instead it is my onCanceled code that does run.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ComposeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final width;
  static const List options = ["Create New Poem", "Load Existing Poem"];

  ComposeButton(this.width);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      child: Container(
          width: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black38,
                blurRadius: 1.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5)
            )],
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Compose",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
            ),
          )
      ),
      onSelected: (dynamic selected){
        print(selected);
      },
      onCanceled: (){
        print("test");
      },
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        return options.map(
          (text) => PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text(text),
          )
        ).toList();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PopupMenuItems must have a **value** property, not only the Text child, [see here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html). This is the value that is given to **onSelected** when the user selects something. I changed your code and it works for me, 1 or 2 is returned on selecting a menu, and if you click outside, "test" is returned:

```
class ComposeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final width;

  // this is not used but you can refactor to include values as well
  // see below
  // static const List options = ["Create New Poem", "Load Existing Poem"];

  ComposeButton(this.width);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      child: Container(
          width: width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  blurRadius: 1.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5))
            ],
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Compose",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          )),
      onSelected: (dynamic selected) {
        print(selected);
      },
      onCanceled: () {
        print("test");
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
        // here you see the values assigned to the popup menu items
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 1,
          child: Text('Create New Poem'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem(
          value: 2,
          child: Text('Load Existing Poem'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```